# LESS.js + @arguments + Skip One Argument

Tags: css, less

I have been searching in Google etc., but I couldnt find what I was looking for (I hope I didnt overlook something).. So I thought my best bet is to ask you guys :)

I am playing around with [LESS-JS](http://lesscss.org) for the first time and I really like it. However I have a little problem now.

I am using the `@arguments` variable like this:

```
.basicBorder(@width:1px, @type:solid, @color:@black){
    border:@arguments;
}
```

Which works as expected. Now when I want the border to be red, I am adding this to the element in my css:

```
.basicBorder(1px, solid, @red);
```

Which also works as expected. However I would like to avoid writing `1px, solid,`, since these are my default values already, but when I try this:

```
.basicBorder(@red);
```

Or this:

```
.basicBorder(,,@red);
```

It doesnt work.

So I was wondering if any1 knows how I could "skip" the first 2 variables so that I can just input the color in case I dont want the border-width and type to be changed.

I hope you get what I am trying to say!

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametric mixins in LESS works sorta like javascript functions, you can't skip the first parameters. So if you want to only change the color, you could rewrite the mixin like this:

```
.basicBorder(@color:@black, @width:1px, @type:solid){
    border:@width @type @color;
}
```

Then you'd be able to call it like this:

```
.basicBorder(@red);
.basicBorder(@red, 2px, dotted);
```

**edit**
Using your original mixin, you could also create these

```
.basicBorderType(@type) {
    .basicBorder(1px, @type, @black);
}
.basicBorderColor(@color) {
    .basicBorder(1px, solid, @color);
}
```

Now you could overwrite any of the styles:

```
.basicBorderType(dotted); //1px dotted black;
.basicBorderColor(@red);  //1px solid red;
.basicBorder(2px);        //2px solid black;
```

A bit of a hack, but it's the only thing I can think of to help you out...

Comment: Right, but the problems remains the same. If I put `@color` at the beginning, but than I would like to just change the border-style, I would have to write `.basicBorder(@red, 2px, solid);`, although I want to change the style only. But when you say that skipping the first parameters is impossible, than I think there is no other way than adding the attribute, which will change most often, in the front. Right?

Comment: @Andrej Yep, that's the problem with LESS, you can't specify which parameters you're sending in. If this is what you want, then you need to create "shortcut" mixins.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that insight. At least I now know its not possible to just skip the first parameters and I can stop trying :)

Comment: Thanks again for that! However I think the best thing is to do what you suggested in the first place. Adding color as first parameter, since it will mostly be the color that changes, than adding the width and finally the type (since I personally almost never use another type than solid).

Answer (score 7):

You actually can name later parameters and skip the first ones.  The syntax for your question is:

```
.basicBorder(@color:@red);
```

You can also use normal ordered arguments at the beginning and pluck out named arguments from the rest of the parameters:

```
.basicBorder(2px, @color:@red);
```

This sets `@width` to `2px`, `@type` to the default, and `@color` to `@red`.  Really nice if you have more seldom used arguments.